# std::array Type Initialization

Tags: c++, templates, aggregate-initialization

With a `std::array` you can initialize it like this:

```
std::array<int,5> myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

If I where trying to create my own array class how would I do something similar?

Comment: see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @Wojciech Awesome!!!!

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg is correct but it's worth noting that [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) doesn't actually have an `initializer_list` constructor. It counts on [`aggregate initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of its data member of type `T[N]`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::array` rely on [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (the *C way* of initializing struct), basically this is valid c++:

```
struct A {
    int values[2];
    size_t size;
};

A a = {{42, 44}, 2U}; // No constructor involved
//     |         |--- a.size
//     |--- a.values
```

Now if you remove the `size` attribute, you get:

```
struct A {
    int values[2];
};

A a = {{42, 44}}; // Valid!
```

But c++ gives you something called *brace-elision* we allow you to omit the inner brackets, so:

```
A a = {42, 44}; // Still valid!
```

Now, just makes `A` a template:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct A {
    T data[N];
};

A<int, 2> a = {{42, 44}};
```

Note that this does not makes use of [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which are used for `std::vector`, `std::list`, and so on.

Also note that:

```
A<int, 2> a1{42, 44}; // Not valid prior to c++14
A<int, 2> a2{{42, 44}}; // Ok even for c++11
```

And note that clang will throw warning whatever the version you use by default.

---

A minimalist version of `std::array` could look like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct my_array {

    T _data[N];

    T& operator[] (size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
    const T& operator[] (size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }

    constexpr size_t size () const { return N; }

    T* begin () { return _data; }
    const T* begin () const{ return _data; }
    T* end () { return _data + size(); }
    T* end () const { return _data + size(); }

};
```

Please note that the standard `std::array` has a lot more stuff than this (a lots of `typedef`s, other `methods`, a lots of overloads, ...), but this is a small base to get you started.

Also note that `_data` has to be `public` so that **aggregate initialization** can work (it does not work if you have `private` / `protected` members!).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation that supports initializing with a list of elements:

```
//template class 'array' takes 'T' (the type of the array) and 'size'
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
class array
{
public:
    //This is the concept of initializer lists (wrapper around variadic arguments, that
    //allows for easy access)
    array(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    {
        //Loop through each value in 'list', and assign it to internal array
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
            arr[i] = *(list.begin() + i); //list.begin() returns an iterator to the firsts
                                          //element, which can be moved using +
                                          //(deferenced to get the value)
    }

    //Overloads operator[] for easy access (no bounds checking!)
    T operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        return arr[index];
    }
private:
    T arr[size]; //internal array
};
```

You can then use it like so:

```
array<int, 2> a = { 2, 5 };
int b = a[0]; //'b' == '2'
```

Comment: What does the member "size" do? You can simply use the template parameter instead

Comment: @KABoissonneault jup, missed that for a sec, thanks :)